# Algebra Polynomials Additional Mathematics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

If $P(x) = 3x^2 - 4x + 2$ and $Q(x)= Ax(x+1)+ Bx+C$  are identical polynomials, then $A+B+C= ?$

Comment: **Hint:** Group like terms, equate terms, solve $A+B+C$.

Comment: 2 things: nice profile pic, and please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Having convinced yourself that you cannot get, for example, a multiple of $x^2$ with some clever constants in $cx+d$, then you know that the coefficients on each power of $x$ must be the same.

$$P(x)=3x^2-4x+2;$$
$$Q(x)=Ax^2+(A+B)x+C.$$

Then $A=3$, $A+B=-4$, $C=2$. You can use the first two equations to find $B$ and take it from there.

Comment: When comments too short, I recommend using `\color { white } { \text{ <invisible comment here> } }`

Comment: I just realized you can also use an even number of $ with a space between as well.

Comment: But the invisible text is cooler.  And you can highlight it with the mouse to reveal the secret message:  $$\text{try!}\to\color{white}{\text{hehehe}}$$

Comment: You're not wrong!